# Show $f(f(b))-f(f(a))=(f'(c))^2(b-a)$ for some $c \in (a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ be a differentiable function with continuous and positive first derivative.

Prove that there exists $c\in(a,b)$,such that

$$f(f(b))-f(f(a))=(f'(c))^2(b-a).$$

My Attempt:

I approached the LHS in following manner:

$$\left(\frac{f(f(b))-f(f(a))}{f(b)-f(a)}\right)\left(\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right)=(f'(c))^2$$

But I am not able to decide which function to use so that LMVT may be applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the first derivative is continuous and positive, this is an increasing function. Therefore,
$$f(b)=l$$
and
$$f(a)=k$$
for some $a\leq k<l\leq b$

Now, first apply LMVT on $[k,l]$, and get,
$$\exists c_1\in (k,l): \frac{f(l)-f(k)}{l-k}=f'(c_1)$$
Now apply LMVT on $[a,b]$, and get,
$$\exists c_2\in (a,b): \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c_2)$$
Now, here continuity and positivity of first derivative works. By, intermediate value theorem, there is $c$ between $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $f'(c)$ is the GM of $f'(c_1)$ and $f'(c_2)$. This is precisely what we require.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: The idea of Geometric mean eluded me. Thanks

Comment: Continuity of derivative is not necessary as derivatives satisfy intermediate value property (Darboux theorem).